# How i can find static pages and change the content for a website built on Ruby program

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Hello i am a web designer and i want to learn Ruby , i have a website running locally on my computer and i want to change a few things on the website i know how to deal with static pages not with pages based on Ruby.

i want to find the static pages in order to change the text or add a new code but i don't know where i can find it! i will copy and past part of piece of code for you to have a clear idea

This code for example what dose it mean where i can find the static page or the controls
ruby run to change the text

**<%= t("pinplus.nav.label_legal") %>**

Comment: Do you know scaffold? And if I were you, I use active scaffold.

Comment: Do you want a content management system? Or are you just creating semi-dynamic pages?

Comment: Check the Ruby on Rails Tutorial Book, which is also available online: https://www.railstutorial.org/book  Chapter 3 covers your static pages.

Answer (score 0):

start here:

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=how+to+install+ruby+on+rails

Then go here:

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=first+rails+app

finnaly here:

http://railscasts.com/

Answer (score 0):

`<%= t("pinplus.nav.label_legal") %>` will output the corresponding text in the locale file labeled as `pinplus.nav.label_legal`.  You will need to update the locale file for the language you want to change.  For example to change the text for english open up `config/locale/en.yml` and look for the `label_legal` key.  The structure of the file should be something like:

```
en:
  pinplus:
    nav:
      label_legal: change me!
```